# Вставить null значение в базе данных MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, null, insert

В базе данных есть столбец time  с типом time, никак не могу записать в него NULL если ничего не приходит

```
public function add_task($user_id, $date, $task_arr){

    $time  =  'NULL';// КОНСОЛЬ ЛОГ ВЫВОДИТ null НО В бд ДОБАВЛЯЕТ 00:00:00
    $time = NULL;// КОНСОЛЬ ЛОГ ничего не выводит НО В бд ДОБАВЛЯЕТ 00:00:00

    //ЕСЛИ НАПРЯМУЮ В ЗАПРОСЕ ПИШУ NULL ТО ДОБАВЛЯЕТ ВСЕ НОРМАЛЬНО null
    //ЕСЛИ В ЗАПРОСЕ ПИШУ '$TIME' OR NULL ТО ЕСЛИ ПУСТАЯ СТРОКА ТО ВСЕ ОК ДОБАВЛЯЕТ NULL 
        //А ЕСЛИ СТРОКА СО ВРЕМЕНЕМ ТО ДОБАВЛЯЕТ 00:00:01

    $task = $task_arr['task_name'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tasks` (`for_user_id`, `time`, `date`, `task`) VALUES ('$user_id', '$time', '$date', '$task')") or die(mysql_error());

    print_r($time);

}//end add_task
```

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329542/php-mysql-insert-null-values

Comment: Пишите, чтобы запрос был не `..., 'NULL' ...`, а `..., NULL ...` - то есть уберите кавычки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри на класс PDO http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php

Твоя проблема в нем решится так:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `tasks` (`for_user_id`, `time`, `date`, `task`) VALUES (:user_id, :time, :date, :task)');
$sth->execute([
    ':user_id' => $user_id, 
    ':time' => $time,
    ':date' => $date,
    ':task' => $task,
]);
```

Почему не стоит использовать функции семейства mysql_query:

- Они уже устарели и в последней версии PHP не поддерживаются
- Если вставлять переменные в запрос так как вставляешь ты, то очень легко сделать инъекцию к твоей БД.

Comment: спасибо. похоже придется, видимо в msql вообще нет такого варианта чтобы решить эту проблему

Comment: спасибо, подошло, и само pdo оказалось полезным и не сложным, 40 минут на обучение=)))

Answer (score 0):

Можете по другому сделать. Столбец поставьте с значением по умолчанию `null` а когда вводите ряд, то забудьте про этот столбец.

Или попробуйте в переменную написать `null` не заглавными буквами.

Ещё не забудьте убрать кавычки:

```
"INSERT INTO `tasks` (`for_user_id`, `time`, `date`, `task`) VALUES ('{$user_id}', {$time}, '{$date}', '{$task}')"
```

Comment: в переменную всяко записывал, ничего не помагает, а вот при отправке запроса немогу забыть про столбец по той причине что столбцов будет в дальнейшем много и данные для заполнения я принимаю в массиве, то есть по задумке если в массиве нет значения то толжна быть запись NULL

Comment: обновил ответ, уберите кавычки от переменной, это же не текст

Comment: для переменной $time в запросе имею в виду

Comment: к сожалению пока тот же результат=(

Comment: а кавычки убрали? покажите как сейчас Ваш код

Comment: работате только если я пишу '$time' OR NULL но если все таки приходит время то в бд почему то нули пишет

Comment: да ковычки убрал, вообще выдает что синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tasks` (`for_user_id`, `time`, `date`, `task`) VALUES ('{$user_id}', {$time } OR NULL, '{$date}', '{$task}')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: пробел после `$time` уберите и `OR NULL` тоже уберите

Comment: убрал, пишет вот такую штуку You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '2018-5-6', 'ddsds')' at line 1

Comment: проверьте что приходит в переменной, если там идёт время, то добавьте кавычки, чтоб ошибки не возникало, а если приходит `null` то кавычки не должны быть

Comment: в кавычках не принимает дату, тоже ошибка.

Comment: Какая ошибка? До этого принимало же

Comment: сори , да принимает не то написал. вобщем пришлось пока решить проблему с помощью if else но по мере увеличения колличества столбцов это будет не реально. а можно ли динамически формировать в запросе столбцы куда идет запись???

Comment: если ответ решил проблему, отметьте его пожалуйста галочкой, а если `if` будет много, можете использовать switch: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php